# How to calculate the distance histogram between two specific super pixels?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am very new to image processing and Matlab. I am working with RGB image and used SLIC algorithm to generate superpixel for an image. By using regionprops to calculate the superpixel properties.

```
[Rcounts binlocations]=imhist(ImageRED);
[Gcounts binlocations]=imhist(ImageGREEN);
[Bcounts binlocations]=imhist(ImageBLUE);
```

Q1: I have 48 superpixels but while checking Counts it is giving me 256*1 double(most of them are zero). Can anybody explain how to refine them to get each superpixel histogram?

Q2: How can I compare two specific superpixel histograms?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance